# Removing gray from RGB. I am using coral to learn programming + its apart of a course

Tags: java, python

Problem :

Summary: Given integer values for red, green, and blue, subtract the gray from each value.

Computers represent color by combining the sub-colors red, green, and blue (rgb). Each sub-color's value can range from 0 to 255. Thus (255, 0, 0) is bright red, (130, 0, 130) is a medium purple, (0, 0, 0) is black, (255, 255, 255) is white, and (40, 40, 40) is a dark gray. (130, 50, 130) is a faded purple, due to the (50, 50, 50) gray part. (In other words, equal amounts of red, green, blue yield gray).

Given values for red, green, and blue, remove the gray part.

Ex: If the input is 130 50 130, the output is:

80 0 80

My code :

integer red

integer green

integer blue

integer gray

red = Get next input

green = Get next input

blue = Get next input

gray = 50

if red >= 50 and red <= 255

red = red - gray

Put red to output

elseif green >= 50 and green <= 255

green = green - gray

Put green to output

elseif blue >= 50 and blue <= 255

blue = blue - gray

Put blue to output

I need help trying to substract the smallest value from an input of three numbers rather than just 50 and output those three integers rather than just the first integer.

Note : I wanted to use the 'min' function but there is not much in the built in library for coral. I think this challenge wants to focus on branching.

(I can fairly read and understand python and java code as well if you wanted to help me using them)

Comment: Comparison operators and branching are enough to find the smallest of 3 numbers. Just take a second to think about it, I'm sure you don't really need help on that one. Why is 2 the smallest of 5,9,2 ? Because 2 < 5 and 2 < 9.

Comment: I understand the logic but I need to translate that to the computer. I used comparison operators and started with branches until I realized I am not substracting the three numbers by the smallest of them. I also seem to be outputting a single integer after. I am new to this so be patient with me.

Comment: No worries. Start with identifying the smallest number and storing it into a variable (gray), output it's content to make sure you get that part right. Then substracting it from the three variables should be easy. I'm still confident you can find that first part yourself but if you are not that confident and still feel stuck, here's where I would start : is red smaller than green ? if it is, you know the smallest is either red or blue. If it's not, you know the smallest is either green or blue. And in both case all you have left is to compare two numbers to find out the smallest

Comment: Here's a java implementation in case you're still stuck : https://ideone.com/hemrxs

Answer (score 0):

```
integer red
integer green
integer blue
integer grey

red = Get next input
green = Get next input
blue = Get next input

if red < green and red < blue 
   grey = red
elseif green < red and green < blue
   grey = green
else 
   grey = blue

red = red - grey
green = green - grey
blue = blue - grey

Put red to output
Put " " to output
Put green to output
Put " " to output
Put blue to output
Put " " to output
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my boy, lmk if you want a code explanation, everything should be as simple as possible

```
red = int(input())
green = int(input())
blue = int(input())

if (red < green) and (red < blue):
    gray = red
elif (green < red) and (green < blue):
    gray = green
elif (blue < red) and (blue < green):
    gray = blue
else:
    gray = red

red2 = (red - gray)
green2 = (green - gray)
blue2 = (blue - gray)

print (red2, green2, blue2)
```

Comment: Please always explain your code inside the post.